# Got two connected BVerts, how to get the BEdge?

Tags: python, bmesh

I've created a couple of `BVerts`:

`v1 = self.bm.verts.new(vector1)
v2 = self.bm.verts.new(vector2)`

I run some python functions on my mesh, and at sometime while doing python stuff on my mesh, a face is created that has these two `BVerts` as adjacent vertices. I don't have that face stored in a variable.

Based on that, I know there is an edge connecting the two vertices. Is there an easy way to get that `Bedge` only using `v1` and `v2`? (I need to feed it into an operation that only takes edges).

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I've figured it out:

`edge = self.bm.edges.get([v1, v2])`